# create a link between ms sql database and my sql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Guys I have a simple question. I have 2 databases on one server one is mssql database and other is mysql database.Is it posssilbe to create a link between these two databases. e.g if a record is inserted into mssql database I want same to be inserted into mysql database.I know it is possible for 2 mssql databases but I want to know is it possible for mysql and mssql databases to communicate like this.Due some problem I cannot use webservice or anything like  that.Thanks in advance

Comment: Replication on different database servers is not possible, I think you should try linked servers here and use triggers to perform the insert, update and delete action on MY SQL from SQL server. REFER the below link to perform the linked server https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mysql-linked-server-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MSSQL databases it's basically called database replication yes.

And between two different databases, you may use linked servers and triggers also (which is what replication do also), like Murtaza said.

Tutorial for linking databases:

- http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221

If you don't need real time update, you could use scheduled task running a custom procedure to merge your data instead of using triggers, which would be better for performance issues